# Pushmeup Gem - Can't send push notifications in Active Admin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, activeadmin

I'm creating a CRM/CMS in Rails using Active Admin.

I've used [Pushmeup](https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup) Gem for the APNS(Apple Push notification service) functionality but I can't seem to make it work.

Here's what I did.

1. Forked the Pushmeup Gem to create my own repository. I've edited the configurations to match my credentials.

   gem 'pushmeup', :git => 'git://github.com/thisisnotme/pushmeup.git'
2. I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup/wiki/APNS-iOS-and-OS-X) here.

Here's my app/admin/token.rb file.

```
  collection_action :apns, method: :get do
    device_token = '7eb2c5fa7f3b0be45cb3613b1d05470c5b76b90929a8ce49d2e511d7b1245d8a'
    APNS.send_notification(device_token, 'Hello iPhone!' )
    APNS.send_notification(device_token, :alert => 'Hello iPhone!', :badge => 1, :sound => 'default')
  end
```

This came up on my screen:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::DeviceTokensController#apns
undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #19):
17
18
19
20
21
22

  collection_action :apns, method: :get do
    device_token = '7eb2c5fa7f3b0be45cb3613b1d05470c5b76b90929a8ce49d2e511d7b1245d8a'
    APNS.send_notification(device_token, 'Hello iPhone!' )
    APNS.send_notification(device_token, :alert => 'Hello iPhone!', :badge => 1, :sound => 'default')
  end
```

It seems that the APNS class is missing. I'm kinda lost. Sorry Rails Newbie.

Comment: try tag `v0.3.0`, not the `master` branch

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ fork it? sorry rails newbie.

Comment: no, just use form `gem 'pushmeup', :git => 'git://github.com/thisisnotme/pushmeup.git', :branch => 'v0.3.0'` in **Gemfile**

Comment: or even simple: `gem 'pushmeup'`, without anything additional

Comment: HI @МалъСкрылевъ    If you aren't forking it, how are you going to override the configurations?     This is the default configuration. APNS.host = 'gateway.push.apple.com' 
# gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com is default

APNS.port = 2195 
# this is also the default. Shouldn't ever have to set this, but just in case Apple goes crazy, you can.

APNS.pem  = '/path/to/pem/file'
# this is the file you just created

APNS.pass = ''
# Just in case your pem need a password

Comment: I believe, you can replace host, and port in the direct call to the APNS methods. but how do you use its confuguration in your project?

Comment: Hi @МалъСкрылевъ  have you actually tried this gem? well in the docu it says replace the configs inside the APNS class.   What I did was fork out the repos. and edited the class in the lib/pushmeup/apns/core.rb

Comment: you can redefine config it without forking

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the host and port are defined as follows:

```
module APNS
   @host = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'
   @port = 2195
   class << self
      attr_accessor :host, :pem, :port, :pass
   end
end
```

So you just can redefine APNS variables, as it is shown in the [README](https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup/blob/master/README.md):

```
APNS.host = 'gateway.push.apple.com'
APNS.port = 2195 
APNS.pem  = '/path/to/pem/file'
APNS.pass = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is kinda late but I had the same error. It was thrown because I did not extract the certificate AND the key from the keychain into a single PEM file.